# how to automatically send cookie contents in requests?

Tags: reactjs, rest

I 'v heard that I can send my cookie contents automatically in axios request with setting header {withCredentials: true}. although I read a lot about it, yet I couldn't be successful working with it. Is there anyone that can explain it from scratch. 
I hope someone can write something on codepen....

Comment: you try to solve it and then when you face a problem come to ask with adding your code that has a problem

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials. Check youtube check google. Come here if you have a very specific question.